# How do i use redirect with ZfcUser?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I want to forward unauthenticated request to ZfcUser login action, then redirect to original request after successful login.

I have this code inside my controller action;

```
// Check we are logged in.
if (!$this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {

    // Set the 'redirect' parameter
    $redirect = $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
    $this->getRequest()->getQuery()->set('redirect', $redirect);

    // Forward request to zfcUser's login action.
    return $this->forward()->dispatch('zfcuser', array(
        'action' => 'login'
    ));
}
```

I have un-commented this line in the ZfcUser config;

```
'use_redirect_parameter_if_present' => true,
```

It does forward to the ZfcUser login action preserving original url, but it does not redirect back to original requested page after login.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have to pass a route as the redirect param, not an URI. If you want to use an URL, take a look at this module: https://github.com/Eye4web/E4WZfcUserRedirectUrl

Comment: Can you provide example code of how to pass a route not a URI

Comment: I believe I'm using an old version that seems to allow redirecting using URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I was overriding the default views with my own. In my view i missed the redirect hidden form element.

Adding the hidden redirect form element solved the redirect problem.

I am also using an old version of ZfcUser, and I believe this feature may have changed between versions.